# Rails 4: Failed to push to heroku (Ruby 2.3.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Hi I get this error while trying to push to heroku. Currently using Rails -v "4.2.1" and ruby "2.3.0" (Bundler 1.14.6). Appreciate if anyone can help! Thank you very much!

```
169-29:SimpleSurvey minhvu$ git push heroku master
    Counting objects: 362, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (303/303), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (362/362), 701.13 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
    Total 362 (delta 53), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Ruby app detected
    remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     An error occurred while installing ruby-2.3.0
    remote:  !     
    remote:  !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
    remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
    remote:  !     
    remote:  !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
    remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
    remote:  !     
    remote:  !     
    remote:  !     Debug InformationCommand: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-16/ruby-2.3.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
    remote:  !     
    remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
    remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
    remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy....
    remote: 
    remote: !   Push rejected to immense-castle-65942.
    remote: 
    To https://git.heroku.com/immense-castle-65942.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/immense-castle-65942.git'
```

Get this second error while trying to upgrade to Ruby 2.3.4 using RVM

```
169-29:SimpleSurvey minhvu$ rvm upgrade 2.3.0 2.3.4
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/minhvu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin' is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for 'PATH=...' entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles'.
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.3.0'.
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.
Are you sure you wish to upgrade from ruby-2.3.0 to ruby-2.3.4? (Y/n): Y
Installing new ruby ruby-2.3.4
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-2.3.4.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
ERROR: '/usr/local/bin' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew doctor' to fix it!
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
Unable to install ruby ruby-2.3.4. Please install it manually to continue.
```

Comment: Is this the first push to Heroku of this app? If not, has it worked before?

Comment: Hi, this is the first push.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to comment `ruby 2.3.0` line in `Gemfile` and push code to heroku.

Comment: I know why this works. It's because I'm using bundler 1.14.6 and bundler below 1.2.0 in heroku will not recognize the ruby 2.3.0 line. Thanks thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you amend the commit or something which is causing the issue

You may try to force push the changes.

```
git push heroku master -f
```

> Note: This will overwrite the old commit history with the new one if you have amend the commit

**Solution 2:**

This error suggest you should try changing the ruby version

```
An error occurred while installing ruby-2.3.0   
Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
```

Can you please try to change the ruby version to `2.3.4`

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back. But this doesn't work :(

Comment: Try changing ruby version to `2.3.4`

Comment: I get a second error while trying to install ruby to 2.3.4 using RVM. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Anyway I'm not sure but I've always been using ruby 2.3.0 in my machine to deploy other apps on heroku. Not sure why it is working this time though :(